# Can't display hyperlink vertically in middle when it's in table cell and 'a' tag is display: block

Tags: html, css

I have a hyperlink in display: block mode and it's placed in a table cell (td). The hyperlink text is showing at the top of the cell. Want it in the middle for all common browsers.

I am using a hover effect where the background color of the cell changes. The text position looks odd.

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862604/html-css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-link  Setting the line-height worked for me, but has a few caveats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution from this page with some minor css modifications:

http://apptools.com/examples/tdcolor.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align : middle;">
<a href="#" style="display : block"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is this what you are looking for? Notice the "vertical-align : middle" in the cell style.

Comment: That won't work.  The link is taking the whole cell space because it's a block. So there's nothing to display in the middle. there's no 'air' to move things around.

Try this test:
<table>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align : middle; border: 1px solid red">
<a href="#" style="display : block;height: 100px; border: 1px solid green">test</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining `line-height` for your `a` element

```
td a {line-height: 2em; /* other css */}
```

This should force the text to be vertically centred. Bearing in mind that, should the text wrap to a second line, you might end up with an undesired end-result.