# HTML-CSS Center Text horizontally and vertically in a link

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make a link which has a `height` and a `width` of 200px.
The text of the link shall be centered vertically and horizontally.

This is my CSS so far:

```
a:link.Kachel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: #383838;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  box-align: center;
}
```

and this the HTML-code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="Kachel" href="#">Test</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The text is horizontally centered but not vertically.

Any idea how to get the text centered both horizontally and virtically?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

remove everything else, and just replace `height` with `line-height`

```
a:link.Kachel{
   width: 200px;
   line-height: 200px;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   background: #383838;
}
```

**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6jSFY/**

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes it is so easy :).

Comment: what if the link has `height: 100%`?

Comment: typically line-height vertically-aligns if its set to 150%, which i would use if the a element's height were set to 100%

Comment: This solution makes a lot of sense, but only if the link text is a single line. I'm currently working to find a way to vertically-align link text that ranges from 1 to several lines.

Answer (score 53):

In CSS3, you can achieve this with a flexbox without any extra elements.

```
.link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: it works better than te accepted answer because it works for links with multiple lines

Answer (score 6):

If the text is only on one line, you can use `line-height:200px;` - where the 200px is the same as the `height` value.

If the text is on multiple lines and will always be on the same number of multiple lines, you can use `padding` combined with `line-height`. Example with 2 lines:

```
line-height:20px;
padding-top:80px;
```

This way the two lines will take up a total of 40px and the padding top puts them perfectly in the middle. Note that you'd need to adjust the `height` accordingly.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ryS7u/).

If there is more than one link and it will have any number of lines, you will need some accompanying JavaScript to *fix* the padding on each.

Answer (score 4):

If the number of rows (or the inner element height) is not known, there is another trick using `display: table` and `vertical-align`:

```
.wrapper{
    display: table;
}
.link{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/strae/ps6w08x2/)

[Full article with details](https://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

Answer (score 2):

Small point to add.  If you remove the underline (text-decoration: none;) then the text will not be perfectly centred vertically. Links leave space for the underline. To my knowledge there is no way to override this except to add little extra top padding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using padding? Like:

```
padding-top: 50%;
```

Comment: How does this differ from the other answers here?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3, you can try to use `line-break` with the justify text.

```
text-align: justify;
line-break: anywhere;
```