# HTML/JS Why Does Including A Checkbox Break Line-Height Vertical Text Centering

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I have div with a checkbox and some text inside of it. I want the text centered vertically, and the solution I found recommended setting the line-height of the div equal to the actual height which causes the text to be centered, the only problem is it breaks if I also include an `<input type="checkbox">`.

Other solutions from stack overflow also recommend using the line-height css: [HTML-CSS Center Text horizontally and vertically in a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862604/html-css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-link). So the typical solution to this problem will not work in my case without a workaround. Heres the relevant HTML code:

```
    <div class="advanced-filter">
        {% for tag_type in tag_types %}
            <div class="tag-box-div">
                    <input class='tag-box' type="checkbox" id="tag-box-{{tag_type.char}}">
                    {{tag_type.name}}

            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

And relevant CSS:

```
.tag-box-div {
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

This CSS will correctly center the text in the "tag-box-div" if I comment out the `<input>`, but if I include the `<input>` the text will not be centered vertically. I am simply going to work around this, but I would like to know why this is happening. Django templating language if that matters.

Comment: try to set `vertical-align` property of the input element to middle for example

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried it and it worked perfectly. I don't know why it worked though, could you explain?

Comment: I am gonna find some related question with needed details